# How to uncheck the mat radio drop down in angular?

Tags: angular, radio-button, angular6

```
<div *ngIf= "selvaluee ==='atm' || 
"selvaluee === 'nonpay'" >
<mat-radio-group>
 <input matInput 
  formControlName="on" [(ngModel)] 
   (change)= 
  "Onchange($event,selval)">
 <mat-radio-button value="yes"> 
  yes </mat-radio-button>
 <mat-radio-button value="no"> no 
  </mat-radio-button>
 </mat-radio-group>
 </div>
```

If an user selects atm or nonpay option on top, I'm displaying this radio button. After selecting radio button, if an user again goes to top & changes the "atm" option by selecting some other option like "nonpay", I need to default the radio button options. Like no options should be selected in the radio button. It should be fresh. Can somebody please tell me how to do this in angular?

Comment: Have you checked the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-binding-eatyxo?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selvaluee" (change)="selection = null">
  <option value="atm">Atm</option>
  <option value="nonpay">Non pay</option>
</select>


<div *ngIf="selvaluee ==='atm' || 
selvaluee==='nonpay'">
    <mat-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selection">
        <input matInput  formControlName=" on" (change)="Onchange($event,selval)">
        <mat-radio-button value="yes">
            yes </mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="no"> no
        </mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
</div>
```